# How to refresh table row until db condition?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have table that prepends with new row via ajax.

**_group.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag_for(:tr, @group, class: 'group-new-row') do %>
    <td><%= group.title %></td>
    <td><%= group.owner_id %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'edit', edit_group_path(:id => group.id), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
      <%= link_to 'delete', group, remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'sure?' },
                  class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
    </td>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.rb**

```
$("#grouptable").prepend('<%= j render(@group)%>');
```

**_table.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="grouptable">

  <%= content_tag_for(:tr, @groups) do |group| %>
      <td><%= group.title %></td>
      <td><%= group.owner_id %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_group_path(:id => group.id), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
        <%= link_to 'delete', group, remote: true, method: :delete,  data: { confirm: 'sure?' },
                    class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
      </td>

  <% end %>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

It is background job that retrieve data via API request. When job is done, record's field called `:new_folow` becomes `false`. How can I periodically refresh this row till `:new_follow` condition is `true`?

In other words:

```
while :new_follow == true do 
 refresh prepended row every 5 seconds
end
```

Comment: Can u explain it more clearly?

Comment: new_follow is in ur js or ruby side?

Comment: @HarryBomrah I tried to do it. pls see last section of question.

Comment: :new_follow is field of db record

Comment: so i guess u r asking that u want to stop the periodic refresh of ur js once new_follow is set to false. am i right?

Comment: Ok. then with every request from ur js, respond it with a flag if it should keep making the request or stop it. u can ve a `new_follow` set to `true` or `false`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that is the way. But I ask how to do this))

Answer (score 0):

In your js

```
var newFollow = true;
var getNewRow = function(){
 if(newFollow){
    $.ajax({
       // ur call here 
    })
  }else{
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}
var interval = setInterval("getNewRow",5000);
```

In your create.js.erb

```
$("#grouptable").prepend('<%= j render(@group)%>');
newFollow = // model.new_follow, this should be true or false;
```

I hope this helps.